# Area of polygon inscribed in a circle

Tags: functions, area

Let $A_n =$ the area of a regular $n$-sided polygon inscribed in a circle of radius $1$ (i.e., vertices of this regular $n$-sided polygon lie on a circle of radius $1$).

($i$) Find $A_{12}$.

($ii$) Find greatest integer ($A_{2014})^c$, i.e., the greatest integer $\le A_{2014}$.

Comment: Note that the area of a regular *n*-gon inscribed in a circle is multiple $2n$ of the area of a certain right triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

A regular polygon with $n$ sides as you describe can be decomposed into $n$ congruent isosceles triangles, each of them has two sides of length $1$ and they form an angle $\theta_n=\frac{2\pi}{n}$, so
$$A_n=n\frac12(1)(1)\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}=\frac{n}{2}\sin\frac{2\pi}{n}$$
Then, for (i) we get
$$A_{12}=\frac{12}{2}\sin\frac{2\pi}{12}=6\sin\frac{\pi}{6}=3$$

Answer (score 2):

The area of that circle is $\pi r^2 = \pi\cdot 1^2 = \pi\approx 3.14159\ldots\,$. If the polygon has a sufficiently large number of sides, then the area of the polygon is close to $\pi$, but always less than $\pi$.  "Close" can be taken to mean more than $3$.  If $2014$ is sufficiently large, then that greatest integer must be $3$.  Look at the picture and guess whether $2014$ seems big enough.

And if that's not enough, use the answer to part $(i)$, which says $12$ is big enough.  If $12$ is big enough, then so is $2014$.

Don't treat the problem as if it says "Do part $(i)$ and also do part $(ii)$.  They're not separate unrelated problems.  The answer to $(i)$ tells you something about the answer to $(ii)$.